# Monitor network with headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools, headless

I'm exciting to use headless chrome, I want some function like `onResourceRequested` in [Phatom.js](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html).

But I did not find the corresponding function for monitoring the HttpRequest. after check the [dev tools documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/), I find many function use `requestId`, but there is not even a function for getting such an Id, how do you do the network monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

[It's there, just a bit buried](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-requestWillBeSent). I eventually want to add this feature to [Navalia](https://github.com/joelgriffith/navalia) as it's both a useful thing, and hard to grep (like a lot of CDP is)